# R: Histogram with both custom breaks and constant width

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have some skewed data and want to create a histogram with custom breaks, but want it to actually look readable w/ constant widths for the bins (which would throw off the scale of the x axis, but that's fine). Does anyone know how to do this in ggplot/R?

This is what I don't want, but I don't know how to make breaks not override the width argument:

```
library(ggplot2)
test_data = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,8,9,14,20,42,98,101,175), c(50,40,30,20,10,6,6,7,9,5,6,4,1))
buckets = c(-.5,.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,10.5,99.5,200)
q1 = qplot(test_data,geom="histogram",breaks=buckets)
print(q1)
```

Not the histogram I want :(

[image: Histogram with variable width bars]

Comment: You could do this in base R using `cut()` to create a factor representing your custom bins, then using `barplot()` to plot the counts in those bins.

Comment: Or to stick with `ggplot` you would do `q1 = qplot(cut(test_data, buckets), geom = "histogram")`

Comment: @choff Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms, sure. Just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ulfelder suggested, use `cut()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
test_data = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,8,9,14,20,42,98,101,175),
                c(50,40,30,20,10,6,6,7,9,5,6,4,1))
buckets = c(-.5,.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,10.5,99.5,200)
q1 = qplot(cut(test_data, buckets), geom="histogram")
print(q1)
```

[image: Barplot showing histogram based on user defined "buckets"]